# Composition with a pointer

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, composition

[image: UML diagram of classes]

I am having trouble with RobotControl class members. The UML specifies the relation between RobotControl’s position and RangeSensor as composition. Doesn't using pointers for them, make them aggregation? How should I declare - create these members with respect to UML, or has UML mistaken?

Comment: I have not seen this particular distinction between aggregation and composition.  Googling, I found: "Aggregation implies a relationship where the child can exist independently of the parent. Example: Class (parent) and Student (child). Delete the Class and the Students still exist. Composition implies a relationship where the child cannot exist independent of the parent."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointers in C++ can be used for both aggregation and composition. The distinction is, as correctly [noted by Douglas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917759/composition-with-pointer-c#comment82803522_47917759), whether the lifetime of the objects is interconnected. In other words: Is the child destroyed when the parent is destroyed? The answer *Yes* stands for composition, *No* for aggregation.

## How do we distinguish these cases in a C++ code?

Pointers in C++ can mean the ownership of another (dynamically created) object, or just refer to an object owned by someone else. Let’s show the differences in examples. I’ll explain why pointers can be useful for each type of relationship.

### Aggregation with a pointer

In this case, it is fine to only forward-declare the `class Child` before `class Parent` declaration and the `child` member can be set and re-set during the lifetime of the `Parent`.

```
class Child;

class Parent
{
public:
    Parent(Child* ch) : child(ch) {}
    Parent() : child(NULL) {}
    void setChild(Child* ch) { child = ch; }
private:
    Child* child;
};
```

### Composition with a pointer

The longest example shows that we can dynamically create and destroy the `child` using a pointer. The `child`’s lifetime is strongly interconnected with the `Parent`. However, we can still swap `child`ren during the lifetime of the `Parent` thanks to pointers. This solution also allows to only forward-declare `class Child` in the header file unlike the alternative below.

```
// --- header file
class Child;

class Parent
{
public:
    Parent();
    ~Parent();
    void renewChild();
private:
    Child* child;
};

// --- source file
#include "child.h"

Parent::Parent()
    : child(new Child)
{
}

Parent::~Parent()
{
    delete child;
}

void Parent::renewChild()
{
    delete child;
    child = new Child;
}
```

#### Disclaimer

This example is a subject to the [Rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). I am intentionally letting the implementation of missing recommended methods up to the user, keeping this answer dialect-agnostic and as simple as possible.

### Composition without pointers

Instead of writing constructor and destructor manually, you can just declare `child` in the class declaration and let the compiler to do the construction and destruction for you. This is valid as long as the `class Child`’s constructor requires no parameters (otherwise you’d need to write `class Parent`’s constructor manually) and the `class Child` is fully declared before the declaration of `class Parent`.

```
#include "child.h"

class Parent
{
private:
    Child child;
};
```

### Aggregation without pointers

To be complete, the alternative to using pointers for aggregation is using a reference. However, this prevents swapping `child`ren during the lifetime of the `Parent` object.

```
class Child;

class Parent
{
public:
    Parent(Child& ch) : child(ch) {}
private:
    Child& child;
};
```

Comment: There's an alarming lack of smart pointers and rule of 3/5/0 in this answer.

Comment: @Quentin You are right. However, trying to solve these problems would add unwanted complexity to my answer, so I rather added a disclaimer. Moreover, since I have just a little experience with C++ beyond C++98 (and even stricter EC++), I offer to make this answer a community wiki if you’d like to supplement it.

Comment: Well, apart from avoiding problems, there's also a clear advantage to a smart pointer here: if you see a `std::unique_ptr` member, you are almost certain that you are in the "composition with a pointer" case. It does it all automatically *and* expresses your intent in a single line. It's hard to call it "additional complexity" :p

Comment: @Quentin The additional complexity stems from the fact that `std::unique_ptr` isn’t available in the C++ dialects older than C++11 (which I use mainly), so I would have to maintain two variants. Moreover, I am demonstrating how can we distinguish plain pointers used in these two cases (which is the heart of the question, I believe), so using a smart pointer that is usable in one of these cases only would be counter-productive.